# java xml parsing error printing node value

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to parse some xml from a remote api, the xml is formed like this:

```
<django-objects version="1.0">
    <object pk="13" model="ballot.poll">
        <field type="CharField" name="question">wwwww</field>
        <field type="DecimalField" name="budget">1</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="option1"></field>
        <field type="CharField" name="option2"></field>
        <field type="CharField" name="option3"></field>
        <field type="CharField" name="option4"></field>
        <field type="CharField" name="pollType">YesNo</field>
        <field type="DateField" name="startDate">2013-05-17</field>
        <field type="DateField" name="endDate">2013-05-17</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="targetGender">M</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="targetMarital">All</field>
        <field type="SmallIntegerField" name="targetMinAge">1</field>
        <field type="SmallIntegerField" name="targetMaxAge">1</field>
    </object>
</django-objects>
```

Here is my parsing code, it crashes when trying to output the nodevaluewith a "println needs message" exception

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(msg.getBytes());

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setCoalescing(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = null;
try {
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Document dom = null;
try {
    dom = builder.parse(is);
} catch (SAXException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch blockk
    e.printStackTrace();
}

org.w3c.dom.Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("field");

**Log.d("number of fields: ",items.getLength());** // this outputs 13 as expected because there are 13 field elements

for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {

    Node item = items.item(i);
    **Log.d("field", item.getNodeValue());** //crash here

}
```

Comment: Can you post the exception or cause of the crash you mention?

Comment: added error, its "println needs a message", like theres nothing being returned by .getNodeValue()

Comment: You're saying that `item.getNodeValue()` is returning null.  Since this is XML have you considered using org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser as described in http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 'element' node contains a number of [child nodes of different types](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp). You want the 'text' node which is always the first child, so you can access it like this...

```
item.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()
```

Or it's more straightforward in Java 1.5 and above as you can call [`getTextContent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) directly.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the node to an element.

```
Element tmpElmnt = (Element) item;
```

Then you can use the appropriate methods from Element class to serve your purpose. You will get detailed documentation of `Element` class [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html),